# /etc/profile not being sourced at login

Tags: linux, bash

I'm having a bit of an issue: Neither of my `/etc/profile` or `/etc/environment` are getting sourced at login!

***i.e:*** After boot, the global variables I've got set in `/etc/profile` (and `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` consequently) or `/etc/environment` are not recognized neither by other GUI apps nor by *bash* on terminal.

Please note that I'm running Linux Mint 17 the Cinnamon edition, which, by default, does source the `/etc/profile` file.

File permissions are `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root` for all of the files in question.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Just in case it matters: what are the file permissions? (On my Mac, which is not Linux, `/etc/profile` is `-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel` where the `wheel` group holds system administrators, I think. Small chance that it might not be sourced if, for example, it's *writable* to others?)

Comment: I've just checked that out.. permissions are  `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 856 Feb 22 15:55 /etc/profile` (for all of the files in question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by adding the following bit of code to the *Display Manager* load script ( `/etc/init.d/mdm` )

```
if [ -f /etc/profile ]; then
    . /etc/profile
fi
```

Now, I've got all my configuration loaded as soon as the Display Manager is fully loaded.
Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 5):

Ran into this with Debian Jessie + Cinnamon + lightdm.

Going backto wheezy, I find that /etc/profile and ~/.profile gets sourced by /etc/gdm/Xsession. This logic appears to be totally missing in "this" jessie setup. So I grabbed this code and copied to a new file in jessie:

**/etc/X11/Xsession.d/70fix_lightdm_gpv**

graeme@jessie:~/Desktop$ cat /etc/X11/Xsession.d/70fix_lightdm_gpv

```
# GPV: 2-May-2015, lightdm + cinnamon forgets to source ANY profiles!!

# First read /etc/profile and .profile
test -f /etc/profile && . /etc/profile
test -f "$HOME/.profile" && . "$HOME/.profile"
# Second read /etc/xprofile and .xprofile for X specific setup
test -f /etc/xprofile && . /etc/xprofile
test -f "$HOME/.xprofile" && . "$HOME/.xprofile"

# Local Variables:
# mode: shell-script
# sh-indentation: 2
# indent-tabs-mode: nil
# End:

# vim:set ai et sts=2 sw=2 tw=80:
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a display manager, you have graphical login. So neither of these files are read. Instead most of the display managers do source the `~/.profile` configuration file.

You should try to configure your `~/.profile` file.

If you are not using a graphical login the files that you mention are in use.

As an alternative you could try to configure your display manager.

Comment: Well I don't know about other DMs but what I can confirm is that my current one, which is MDM, does source the `/etc/profile` file.
Anyway,  even the `~/.profile` is not being sourced.