# Which configuration file should now be used for global settings in Ubuntu (/etc/profile not being sourced)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, path, alias

I have a Ubuntu workstation with graphical desktop. I also allow some other users to acess it remotely.
I have a set of general aliases, PATHs and settings (including a system-wide conda installation) that i want to automatically apply to ALL users (Not individually set in each `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` for each individual user).
In the past (ubuntu 14.04), I could simply add respective scripts that applied these settings in `/etc/profile.d/`, and they would automatically be sourced at login via `/etc/profile`.

However, I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 (Yes late, but better late than never...), and now it seems that `/etc/profile.d` is not sourced for users that log in locally into the graphical desktop?

I have seen [solutions](https://superuser.com/questions/881102/etc-profile-not-being-sourced-at-login) to this that include adding a line that sources `\etc\profile` into `/etc/init.d/mdm`, but that seems rather like a hack to me, and not intuitive in any way (e.g. do i need to edit different files if i use different display managers?).

What is currently the file to edit, in order to apply settings to ***all*** users, ***regardless*** of whether they log in locally via graphical user interface or remotely via command line?

Comment: Are you using the shell (and which one), or GUI?

Comment: @harrymc: I am working both on the shell (personally bash, but other users can choose theirs freely), and use grahical user interface (xfce4). I log in via graphical user interface (xfce4) and just start a terminal when i want to work on the command line.

Comment: It would be best for you to paste the actual content of your `/etc/profile` and "setting" files in `/etc/profile.d/` (with their file names) that are "apparently ignored / skipped".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have identical profile and bashrc settings for every user, you can just symlink these files to the same version. E.g. have the originals for the root user on `/root/.bashrc` and then link them using:

```bsh
ln -s /root/.bashrc $HOME/.bashrc
```

Or even better, create a shared `/srv` folder and in there create a folder called `dotfiles` where you keep all your files and optionally(but recommended) version all your dotfiles with git.

Comment: Thanks, but sadly that is not a nice solution for me as, (1.) it needs manual changes (symlinking) for each individual user. And that is bound to be error prone at some time (e.g. forgetting to symlink in some cases). and (2.) I would absolutely not want identical settings for all users! I just want certain PATHS and aliases to be set for all users. This used to be easily possible by just placing scripts into /etc/profile.d that set the aliases and add to PATH. But this is apparently NOT a possibility anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Bash can be compiled with the `-DSYS_BASHRC` option (which should be the case in Ubuntu) that makes it sources a system-wide rc file for interactive shell. The path is usually `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

For "settings" (which is quite a vague word btw) that should be applied in  non-interactive shell, it should probably be set in whatever script itself that requires them. (Unless the script is always ran from an interactive shell and the settings can be inherited from that.)

While you might be able to "set" that sort of stuff in one of the profile files that is sourced by a login shell, you might not be "logged in" with the login shell in some circumstances (I don't know if that's your case but I can at least think of one like, you have x11vnc and a dedicated Xvfb started by a systemd user service, then you remote in with a VNC client).

There's at least one exception though, which is environment variable (e.g. `PATH`). For that you may want to see the approach of [this](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/environment.d.html) help in your case, assuming you are / Ubuntu is using systemd. (This is probably what you want to look into if what you run does not involve a shell at all, like GUI programs and systemd user units.)